# Easy Garbage Collection in C

Tags: c, garbage-collection

My main question is: how do I write a simple to understand C garbage collection algorithm? I am trying to learn C (not C++ yet) and write my own C garbage collection algorithm, but I have run into problems. How do I know when my structs are ready to be freed? How do I know when the structs are ready to be released inside functions after they are returned? Should I use structs with or without pointers? I found this post that says garbage collection is easy:
https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/94327-garbage-collection-not-so-complicated.html

I was wondering what “The dynamic objects are stored in an union with a type tag and a mark bit” and what “Use double indirection for the objects” means? Is this really an easy way to do this? How do I write this in C code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By just reading the link it says it's "not so complicated", what might be quite different from "it's easy". If you have no restrictions whatsoever on your task I'd consider your task "complicated enough" - at last.

Comment: Well I will keep working on learning C. Objective-C makes it look so easy with ARC.

Comment: A gc per-se is not complicated indeed. But choosing the right approach, implementing the algorithm to suit your needs, design the interface and how to integrate into the application code, etc. requires quite some experience. With all due respect: from your question, I have doubts you have the latter at least. Enthusiasm is often not sufficient for programming. You first might want to start with something less - sophisticated.

Comment: Regarding ARC, it looks easy because Apple's team(s) put in the work to make it look that way. Apple's docs describe it as a compiler feature, meaning other Objective-C library implementations such as GNUstep would require similar compiler support, including the recognition of the new lifetime qualifiers (e.g. work on GCC/Clang and/or Binutils would be necessary). ARC uses that compiler support to determine where to automatically insert retain/release cycles. Otherwise, ARC isn't possible because there's no reliable way to automatically know when an object is no longer used.

Answer (score -2):

The super simple way to do garbage collection would be to somehow keep a count of the number of references there are to the malloc'd location.  When that counter hits 0 then free() that memory location.

That being said, it may not make as much sense to do garbage collection in C, as with C you don't have objects and other structures than lend themselves to being "collected", so you must manage your memory more directly.

Comment: The question is already not well suited for stack overflow. And there are very well reason to use a gc in C. How else would the C reference implementation of Python be able to work? A gc is not bound to OOP and you can do OOP in C, too. It is not even complicated if well thought.

Comment: I'm sure there are many reason to use it in C, and I didn't say it was not valid - but given the question relates to C++ vs C, I was questioning the need.  It very much depends on what you are doing.

Comment: I don't see anything supporting your claim this is "C vs. C++". And what you write in your answer is not even partially about C++, you effectively say "gc in C does not make much sense".

Comment: I think I made clear why there should be no answer for the question. FYI: I have implemented various GCs for large C (and one Assembly) projects which otherwise would have been much more complicated (and would not support the features they do now).